# Find Data Attribute with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I am trying to find data numbers in the div however, whatever combination I have tried it's giving me syntax error. Am I missing out something?

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        var members = $("div").find("[data-number='"i"']");
        console.log(members);
    }
```

Comment: you need pluses on each side of the i

Comment: totally forgot about that. thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot concatenation with `+`:

```
var members = $("div").find("[data-number='" + i + "']");
```